# How can I give my players edit access only for Session Reports in World Anvil?

Tags: tools, world-anvil

My players are aspiring to take better notes, and I'd like to let them edit them as session reports in [World Anvil](https://www.worldanvil.com/), without exposing all of my plot to them.

I've already set them up as writers, but I can't see options to give the edit access to only some articles.  How can I give them permission to just the Session Reports articles?

Answer (score 6):

### This feature is not implemented in World Anvil

Here is the Editor role from the [Guide to Authors](https://www.worldanvil.com/w/WorldAnvilCodex/a/coauthors)

> #### Editor
>
> Editors can create articles and publish them, and they can also edit existing content. They have **access to all private content**, including secrets.

There is no document-granularity management of the editing rights. This is explicit [in this *closed* Feature request ticket](https://www.worldanvil.com/community/voting/suggestion/333215e4-3b43-41a4-8c08-9cb5f896416e/view) asking for such granular rights to enhance World Anvil, which has the feedback:

> Hasn't reached target 300 votes in 20 days - Feel free to re-suggest at a later time
>
> **Comment**
>
> Authors will not get granular permissions. but Advanced Writers will be getting much more powerful in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Hey there this is Dimitris the CTO of World Anvil. Just confirming that it is true that while, currently making someone a co-author is the way to go if you want your players to contribute DIRECTLY is the only way, there is a major update coming that will see the players having much more power to change things.

This is not announced yet, but players will become their own special type of author that will allow them the ability to have their own sections on Session Reports, their own map pins on your maps, access to write on timelines and among others the ability to add articles UNDER their character/party articles.

This will be coming with the Hercules update :)

Comment: Thanks for the official response!